# adding border spacing around div's border

Tags: css

I have a div that I've got that's circular using `border-radius: 50%` what I also want to achieve is mimicking something I've already seen implemented on hover.

[image]

spacing between the border and the div.

I've tried adding `padding: 5px` to the hover but it doesn't create a border that's not on the div.

### Code

```css
#sub-section .content .icon-div {
  background-color: rgba(204, 202, 202, 0.25);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 13%;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  transition: all ease .3s;
}

#sub-section .content .icon-div:hover {
  border: 1px solid #f6653c;
  background-color: #f6653c;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: all ease .3s;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve], instead of just CSS snippets without context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example using an inset `box-shadow`, as it's less likely to mess with your layout than animating padding:

(Bare in mind, it's not true transparency, the white inner circle is a set colour, which may or may not fit your need)

```css
#example{
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: #f6653c;
  border: 2px solid #f6653c;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,1);
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
}
#example:hover{
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
```

```html
<div id="example">Hover me</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a radial gradient:

```css
div {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:1px solid #FA532A;
}

.simple-radial {
  background: radial-gradient(#FA532A 54px, rgba(204, 202, 202, 0.25) 2px, white 4px);
}
```

```html
<div class="simple-radial"></div>
```

Comment: works nicely with one offset, the edges of the circle looks jagged.

Comment: yeah that's what I thought too, tried to smooth it with that opaque colour but I don't know enough about radial gradients to do it nicely (I'm sure there would be a way)